# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, createjs

Button.js:

```
(function () {
    function Button(label) {
        console.log(label);
    }
}());
```

demo.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="../../lib/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Button.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var canvas, stage, button;
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
            button = new createjs.Button("Anything");
            stage.addChild(button);
            stage.update();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200>Canvas is not supported</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

for the line 
button = new createjs.Button("Anything");
Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
Why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `Button` is not in a global scope or `window`.

You don't need IEFE here. Remove it:

```
function Button(label) {
   console.log(label);     
}
```

If you want it with IEFE, then do this:

```
$(function () {
    window.Button = function (label) {
        console.log(label);
    }
});
```

Comment: How to make it global?

Comment: And now there are 2 errors Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: In mozilla, it shows : TypeError: createjs.Button is not a constructor

Comment: @GauravArora, try removing `new` in that line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `Button` by using `createjs.Button`, then you must create `Button` on the `createjs` object:

```
createjs.Button = function(label){
    console.log(label);
};
```

The above will work in any scope, including the global and your function expression, because `createjs` is in the global scope. Now you can do:

```
button = new createjs.Button("Anything");
```