# Firebug: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined, typeerror

During Bug testing of my Joomla 3.3 Website, Firebug showed the following Error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  scripts.js:123
```

I checked the script.js but couldn't find the problem. Here ist the code, starting in line 120:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var $container = jQuery('.full-portfolio .items');

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
});
```

Comment: So `imagesLoaded` isn't a function. Why do you think it should be?

Comment: This means there's no `imagesLoaded` method. Have you loaded the plugin that defines this?

Comment: @Mouser The error is happening on the line before that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930899/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: You're not ending the function you're sending to `jQuery(document).ready` - you need another `});` at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

1. do you have jQuery defined, check in console by typing jQuery
2. jQuery('.full-portfolio .items') selector probably returns empty array check with console.log($container);